# Question marked as spam/offensive - unable to see complete revision history?

Tags: support, specific-question, spam, offensive

I noticed that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2830438/144766) I answered about a  month ago was deleted and marked as spam/rude/abusive.

However, [revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2830438/revisions) seems to suggest nothing of the sort.

The originally posted question was certainly valid (and included context). It also included a link to an image. I then made an edit converting the link to an actual image. The OP rollbacked several times between the original version and my edited version.

Is it possible that an offensive version was added afterwards, but then censored and hence invisible in the revision history? If not, why was the question deleted?

Comment: It was deleted because six spam flags were cast on it. Why the flags were cast, I have so far no idea.

Comment: Things look fishy. I'm going to push this over to the people with more powerful tools.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There never was an offensive revision of the question.

Some accounts have been used to cast frivolous spam flags to delete it. A CM has looked into things and took appropriate measures.

The question is undeleted again (with the answers of course).